# shell awk two values in input file substract first value from second

Tags: shell, awk

*I have an input file 'numbers':

> ```
> 23,35
> 69,3
> 357,17
> ```

*

I need to subsruct 35 from 23 and others using awk.  My code is:

```
awk '{FS=", "; x=$1; y=$2; z=x-y; print x "-" y "=" z}' numbers
```

I am getting a weird comma in the first line I dont know how to fix it. My output is:

> ```
> 23,-35=-12
> 69-3=66
> 357-17=340
> ```

Comment: You don't set `FS` until after the first line has been read and tokenized.

Comment: Could you please do let me know if my answer has helped you?

Comment: RavinderSingh13 yes it did thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following. You need to set `FS` in `BEGIN` section itself. `BEGIN` is the section which gets executed before reading an Input_file's lines. Also you need not to use variables for substituting values you could directly use field numbers to substract them.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {print $1-$2}' Input_file
```